# Recursive function in Python does not change list

Tags: python, list, recursion, user-defined-functions

I am using a recursive function on a list of lists with an accumulator, but instead of creating the right list of lists, it makes a list with duplicates of the last item inserted in the accumulator. I recreated the problem in a much simpler recursive function and list. This function takes a list of lists and makes 2 copies and reverses them n times.

```
def recursauto(x, n, instSet):
    #Base Case
    if(n==0):
        instSet.append(x)
        print(x) #Print to see what SHOULD be added
    else:
        temp = [x]*(2)  # Make a list with 2 copies of the original list
        for i in range(len(temp)):
            temp[i][i] = temp[i][i][::-1] # Make the list backwards
        for i in range(2):
            recursauto(temp[i], n-1, instSet) #Input each element

MyList = [] #Empyt list for accumulator
print("Correct output:")
recursauto([["A", "l", "e", "x"], ["A", "b", "d", "a", "l", "a", "h"]], 2, MyList)

print("Wrong printed list:")
for i in MyList:
    print(i) #Print what is in the accumulator
```

The output comes out wrong and the accumulator does not have the right things that were put into it.

```
Correct output:
[['A', 'l', 'e', 'x'], ['A', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'h']]
[['A', 'l', 'e', 'x'], ['A', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'h']]
[['x', 'e', 'l', 'A'], ['h', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'A']]
[['x', 'e', 'l', 'A'], ['h', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'A']]
Wrong printed list:
[['x', 'e', 'l', 'A'], ['h', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'A']]
[['x', 'e', 'l', 'A'], ['h', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'A']]
[['x', 'e', 'l', 'A'], ['h', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'A']]
[['x', 'e', 'l', 'A'], ['h', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'A']]
```

I know that there is an easier way to do this, but the function I'm actually making requires recursion. Like I said, this is just a simplified recreation of the problem I am having.

Comment: What would be the correct output?

Comment: The correct output is the list that is going into the accumulator. This is the same thing as what is printed before the "Wrong printed list:" line in the output.

Comment: What is the purpose of the recursive function?

Comment: It just creates 2 copies and reverses the strings every n times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp = [x]*(2)
```

The above line does not create a list of two *copies* of the original list; in fact, it just stores a reference to the same original list twice. If you want a distinct copy of `x`, try using the list copy constructor like `temp = [list(x), list(x)]` or alternatively the shallow [copy method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) `[x.copy() x.copy()]`.

See the below example.

```
>>> ls = ['a']
>>> dup = [ls] * 2
>>> dup
[['a'], ['a']]
>>> ls.append('b')
>>> dup
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: More general solution: `[MyList for i in range(a)]` where a is the number of independent lists thats are required. Use the * operator only if you want to initialize a list of hashable items such a numbers or None, not for lists of lists.

Comment: The problem is that I actually do that because I need a list with 2*n copies of x, so I have been doing temp = [x]*(2*n). What's the alternative to that?

Comment: @AbdalahEl-Barrad like Michael said: `[x.copy() for i in range(n * 2)]`

Comment: However if x is a number, the * operator will do.